# Springboot JdbcTemplate Autowired failed

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jdbctemplate

I'm trying to access database using springboot, however spring application throws an exception below.

> Error creating bean with name 'welcomeController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate com.mysite.soLexiconWebSpring.jsp.WelcomeController.dataSource; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

Which I think is mainly

> org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate] found for dependency

that indicates that no bean is created from application config file.
However I googled for a while and got no luck. Can anybody tell me how to inject JdbcTemplate Correctly?

Here is my POM:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <!-- Your own application should inherit from spring-boot-starter-parent -->
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>soLexiconWebSpring</artifactId>
    <groupId>com.mysite</groupId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>Spring Boot Web JSP Sample</name>
    <description>Spring Boot Web JSP Sample</description>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <url>http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/</url>
    <organization>
        <name>Pivotal Software, Inc.</name>
        <url>http://www.spring.io</url>
    </organization>
    <properties>
        <main.basedir>${basedir}/../..</main.basedir>
        <m2eclipse.wtp.contextRoot>/</m2eclipse.wtp.contextRoot>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
            </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <useSystemClassLoader>false</useSystemClassLoader>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Application.properties

```
spring.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.view.suffix=.jsp
application.message=Hello SuperLucky

#spring.datasource basic database parameter
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/so_lexicon
spring.datasource.username=xxx
spring.datasource.password=xxx
#set data pooling provider to org.apache.tomcat
spring.datasource.type = org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource
#tomcat datasource settings
spring.datasource.tomcat.initial-size=20
spring.datasource.tomcat.max-wait=2000
spring.datasource.tomcat.max-active=100
spring.datasource.tomcat.max-idle=16
spring.datasource.tomcat.min-idle=4
spring.datasource.tomcat.test-on-connect=true
spring.datasource.tomcat.test-on-borrow=true
spring.datasource.tomcat.test-on-return=true
```

Application

```
package com.mysite.soLexiconWebSpring.jsp;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan
public class SampleWebJspApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(SampleWebJspApplication.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(SampleWebJspApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Controller

```
package com.mysite.soLexiconWebSpring.jsp;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;

import com.mysite.soLexiconWebSpring.jsp.beans.FullLexiconRowBean;
import com.mysite.soLexiconWebSpring.jsp.beans.LoginTokenBean;
import com.mysite.soLexiconWebSpring.jsp.dao.LexiconDaoImpl;
import com.mysite.soLexiconWebSpring.jsp.utils.DBUtils;

@Controller
public class WelcomeController {

    @Value("${application.message:Hello World}")
    private String message = "Hello World";

   @Autowired
   private JdbcTemplate dataSource;

    @Autowired
   private DBUtils dbUtils;

    @RequestMapping("/soLexiconWebSpring")
    public String welcome(Map<String, Object> model) {
        model.put("time", new Date());
        model.put("message", this.message);
        return "welcome";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/soLexiconWebSpring/login")
    public String login(@RequestParam("username") String username, @RequestParam("password") String password, Map<String, Object> model)
    {
       LoginTokenBean loginToken = new LoginTokenBean();
       loginToken.setUsername(username);
       loginToken.setPassword(password);
       model.put("loginToken", loginToken);


       LexiconDaoImpl lexRowDao = new LexiconDaoImpl(dataSource);
       List<FullLexiconRowBean> result = lexRowDao.getLexiconRow(1, 5);
       if(result != null) model.put("result", result);
       else model.put("result", dbUtils.getLastException().toString());

       dbUtils.setLastException(new Exception("A B C"));
       model.put("dbUtils", dbUtils);

       return "lexicon";
    }

}
```

Comment: Code as provided compiles just fine. Check com.mysite.soLexiconWebSpring.jsp.mentioned in the exception (and not shown above).

Comment: Why dont you just use `@SpringBootApplication` instead of `@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan` ??

Comment: @mrkernelpanic it's from a maven auto generated project which uses an old version of springboot that has not implement that annotation yet.

Comment: @mp31415 all my Java class are in that package. Can you provide your testing code for reference?

Comment: spring-boot-starter-parent artifact in your pom has version 1.0.2.RELEASE. This is from 2014 are you serious?? Why dont you just use the most recent version 2.0.4.RELEASE?

Comment: @mrkernelpanic It's generated from maven project repository, I'll build one using most recent version for a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for @mrkemelpanic, I updated my project to springboot 2.0.4 (with some effort), and it finally works. So it might be a 1.0.2 bug or something.
Thanks.